# Get activity theme from network and apply it programmatically

Tags: android, download, themes

I want to download themes.xml from network because i need dinamically change application theme.
So after application starts, download file themes.xml from network, saves it locally and apply to current activity.

How i can do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in oncreate functions, get the value from network and do like this:

```
if (valueRecievedFromNetwork == "Dialog")
    this.setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Dialog);
else if.......
```

Comment: Sorry,i saw theme values. For example in my theme there is "textColor" attr applyed to textview. So, after application starts, i retrieve "textColor" value from network and now i want to save it on sd and apply to activity theme. I've founded http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#applyStyle(int, boolean) I think i can read current activity theme with this.getTheme() and after apply theme values in this way this.getTheme().applyStyle(int,boolean) but i'm not sure.